# AppleScript move mouse only

Tags: applescript, mouse, move

is there any way to move mouse without click on mac？
I tried to use AppleScript to move mouse， but fail。

```
tell application "Extra Suites"
     ES move mouse {200,200}
end tell
```

error with : expected "given","with","without",other parameter name,etc. but found identifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of Extra Suites (which hasn't worked for a while now), consider cliclick (https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/).

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick m:" & "222,333"
```

Comment: No longer works.